# how do site collection administrators get to see items for a targeted audience?

Tags: audience-targeting

I've run into a conundrum. There are some navigation items that I'd like to limit to Site Owners. Implicitly, however, I'd also like to have Site Collection Admins have access to these items so that they can help out a site owner if the need arises.

But audience targeting doesn't work as I expected. Site Collection Administrators don't get to see these items. Not only that, but there doesn't seem to be a way to add them to the target audience -- unless I add the names of the admins to the Site Owners group (which I'd rather not do if I can avoid it).

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

TIA
Josh

Comment: Can't they just work in Site Content with information, and Site Settings to configure navigation?

Comment: I don't see the relevance of your question, sorry.

Comment: Maybee I was not expressing myself good enough. It was just a thought about using Site Content or Content and structure to work with information (for your site collection owners) to overcome these obstacles

Answer (score 0):

Site Collection admins have the ability to see everything but it still adheres to audience targetting if it's being used. So in your situation, you'll either need to add them to the Site Owners group, or create a new Group for SCAs, don't grant the group any permissions and add them to the target audience in the navigation.

Comment: PirateEric: Adding an SCA group with no extra permissions is quite elegant. Better yet, if this were made into an AD group, it would always be kept up to date. Thanks very much.